# Rails update price field on item select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form for purchase_orders and purchase_order_lines.

purchase_order_line has attributes ingredient_id, quantity, price.

I am trying to get price updated in real time when an ingredient is selected.

purchase_order_line_fields

```
 <div class="purchase_order_lines">
  <div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= select_tag "ingredients", "", class: "ingredients" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.input :quantity, id: "quantity", input_html: {value: '1'}%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <%= f.input :price, class: 'price' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <%= f.input :total_amount, class: "total_amount", readonly: true %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ingredients').change(function(){
    var ingredient_id = $(this).val();
    var price = eval($(this).data('price'));
  $('.price').html(price)
})
})
```

The event listener is working, but when i select a new ingredient on dropdown price value becomes blank. The second problem I have is that if i change an ingredient on dropdown all price fields for all purchase_order_lines get updated, not only then one when a new ingredient was selected. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem with price being blank, you are trying to get the value of a `data-price` attribute which does not exist. You want to do:

```
var price = parseFloat(this.value);
```

For the problem of all `.price` getting updated at the same time, you neet to target only siblings of the current `.ingredients`:

```
$(this).siblings('.price').html(price);
```

The `.siblings` method searches adjacent elements (children of the jquery object's parent direct parent) with the provided selector.

You should have all `purchase_order_line_fields` wrapped in a div element, if you have all the `purchase_order_line_fields` with the same parent element it won't work.

By the way, check your ids, the way you have definied them you will have multiple elements with the same id, which is not valid html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your solution it's still not updating price. In console I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null' everytime I select a new element in dropdown. Do I need 'var ingredient_id = $(this).val();' and is it correct?

Comment: Hmmm `this` shouldn't be null in that context, add a `debugger;` line at the beginning of the code and debug it, your original code doesn't even have options so I'm not sure what your current code looks

Comment: I have posted the full form for nested fields. For the script I replaced var price = eval($(this).data('price')); and $('.price').html(price) with the code you provided. Anyway I will try to debug and see if i can fix it..

Comment: This is what I get when I inspect html for price field'<input class="form-control numeric decimal optional" type="number" step="any" name="purchase_order[purchase_order_lines_attributes][1535397686849][price]" id="purchase_order_purchase_order_lines_attributes_1535397686849_price">'

Comment: I got it working but I used $('.price').html(price);. For some reason $(this).siblings('.price').html(price); won't work

Comment: `$('.price').html(price)` will update ALL the elements with class `price`, siblings may not work because I don't know your whole html

Comment: Yes that's the problem I'm still having. Trying to clean the html now..

Comment: try doing `$(this).parents('.row').find('.price')`